# Grails: What is the difference between extending and embedding a domain class?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I'm very new to the Grails framework, so please bear with me.

Nonetheless, I am a bit confused on the functionality difference between extending a domain class and embedding objects.
From a database point of view, they both do the same thing. When embedding an object, all the properties of all the classes are stored in one table. Similarily, when extending a class (using table-per-hierarchy), all the properties of all the classes are stored in one table.

I'm sure there is a functionality difference between these two, and so I figured I ask this question.
When do you use either one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only technical difference is the ability to have multiple tables through the table per subclass property when extending a class. Otherwise, they are identical in use.

However, that said, by extending another class you are also modeling that within the class structure so you can make use of instanceof and polymorphic features of Java/Groovy.

Comment: I thought you can only have multiple tables through the table-per-subclass property, and not through table-per-hierarchy.  
    

And I completely forgot about instanceof and polymorphic usage. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, it's per subclass. I have updated the answer.